# Change the output stream of exec command in MSSQL

Tags: java, sql-server, sockets, output

I need to change the output stream from the exec command while executing a stored procedure in MSSQL so that instead of a file i can write the output to a socket and get it remotely. I will be remotely accessing the system and hence will not have access to anything except the database. Hence i need to get the data into my socket instead of the file.

The syntax for exec command is :

```
exec sql_dump '-d (databasename) [-t (tablename)] [-f (outputfilename)] [-a] [-s]'
```

> ```
> -d (databasename) : The database whose backup is to be taken
> -t (tablename) : This option is to be used if you need to take the structure or 
> data belonging to a particular table only. [Optional - If omitted then all the 
> tables are involved in the dump process]
>
> -f (outputfilenamewithpath) : This option is to be used if you need to specify 
> the path and name of file to which dump is to be written. [Optional - 
> If omitted then the dump is stored at the Backup folder found in the 
> installation directory of MS SQL Server, with database name as the filename.]
>
> -s : Dumps the database Schema also.
>
> -a : Dumps the data found inside the database also.
> ```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: From the `-f` option description it seems you have no other choice than store into a file first; you can always reopen the file afterwards and send its contents via a socket

Comment: `sql_dump` is not a valid [tag:sql-server] function. Are you sure that you did not mean [tag:MySQL]? Or is this just a custom coded proc that you are trying to use?

Comment: Is this http://www.wisdombay.com/downs/sqldump.php where you got the this utility from? If so it looks like it was just designed to write to a file. Also it seems to be really outdated, only tested on SQL-2000 and SQL-2005